# add a drag behaviour on a cubism graph

Tags: d3.js, cubism.js

cubism.js is probably meant for realtime vizualizations, not really for interaction, yet I was trying to be able to visualize a large dataset (for example >> 1000points) on the page, without increasing the step or chunking the data

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/B2WJM/4/ (the first 500 points of a 4000 points dataset are drawn)

```
var context = cubism.context()
    .step(6e4)
    .size(500)
    .stop();
```

So the idea would be to drag, or zoom this graph using d3 https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior, hoping there's a nice solution possible by changing dynamically the start and stop attributes

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to show the stock data described [here](http://xaranke.github.io/articles/cubism-intro/) into 3 pieces. I split my graph into 3 and added a carousel-like left/right button to toggle between them.

I think that you can split your data into 5 pieces of 800 px each which you can then move using the left/right buttons.

Comment: it's quite frustrating to not being able to zoom out and see all points, I would like a cubism.js in svg so much

Comment: Yeah...I agree with you.

Comment: I'm trying to make something based on a very large canvas, but it seems to not draw anything after 8000px, see http://jsfiddle.net/B2WJM/11/ it works with 8000px, not 8500

Comment: on the other hand I might just start from horizon in svg http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1483226

Comment: I didn't probably say it explicitely, but I'm waiting for a bit more than a suggestion. For example in a config with a step of 1 minute, and a range of 2 months, the canvas handles half a day, so it's 120 graphs to represent, in a carousel-like way as you suggest